# What does [ ] mean when used with cin?

Tags: c++

I'm currently new to C++ and had a question. Here is the code:

```
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> numbers(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> numbers[i];
    }
    int product = MaxPairwiseProduct(numbers);
    cout << product << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Im trying to study this code and notice the 6th line: `cin >> numbers[i];`

What exactly does the `[ ]` function do?

I understand cin is inputting a value but does the `[i]` override that or?

Comment: It has nothing in particular to do with `cin`. It's the array access operator of `vector<int>`. `numbers[i]` is the `i`th element of `numbers`.

Comment: Consider going through some C++ tutorial or book - specifically what would help here is something on [Arrays](https://www.learn-cpp.org/en/Arrays).

Comment: The brackets [ ] are used to access elements of a C array. It became a notational convention (also many other programming languages use it that way). That is the reason that std::vector also provides access to a specific element with [ ]. For your own class types you can provide any function(ality) you want, when using [ ].

Answer (score 3):

`numbers[i]` has nothing to do with `cin`. It's just returning a reference to the i-th element of `numbers`.

Hence, `cin >> n` means store the input in `n` and `cin >> numbers[i]` means store it in the i-th element of `numbers`.